How can I include one file in another with Shopify?
I'm going through a learning process with my first Shopify theme development. I've customised the bought theme to within an inch of where we want it, now I just want to be able to add a custom section to the Product admin page so I can show a call to action specific for each product.
The .liquid file I have created within the Sections folder is cta.liquid and the file I'm trying to include the request to get that file is the product-template.liquid file, also within the Sections folder.
Here is my code trying to call the cta.liquid file: {% section 'cta' %}
I've also tried using render and include to call the file.
With the above arrow I just get this error message on the website:

Liquid error (sections/nov-product-template line 161): Could not find asset snippets/cta.liquid

The file itself shows no errors.
Thanks for any help.
Tried using include, render, section, sections. I tried to change the file to the snippets folder but I got an error about schema then

Please see [ask]. Titles should be a clear, specific question without tags. Also take the [tour].

In shopify, you can't render section liquid in the section liquid. so you have to create a new snippet for cta liquid file and include in section liquid. In a word, cta should be snippets/cta.liquid not sections/cta.liquid
